# How do I make sure my R session attached is using the compute node instead of the admin (i.e. login) node?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, ssh, slurm, hpc

I am using VS Code for R in a remote Unix environment. My goal is to perform regular interactive job while editing the script on the remote server as what people usually do in RStudio locally.

For the HPC server I use, there're a admin node (i.e. login node) and a compute node (mostly for interactive job).

Usually what I did, is to login in via admin node first (via ssh), and then request certain resourses (e.g. memories, cpu, etc) from the compute node, and then do

```
ssh $SLURM_JOB_NODELIST
```

which transfer me from 'admin' to 'compute' node in the terminal.

And lastly, I do "R: Create R terminal". **However, I wouldn't be able to check if this R terminal is operated on the compute node or the admin node.**

There's a way to go around, by using 'radian' package and set "r.alwaysUseActiveTerminal" as "true". However, via this way, my data viewer wouldn't be attached and I couldn't view my data in the 'workspace'. As this,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTnmU.png)

The trickiest part is I need to use 'ssh' to switch between 'admin' and 'compute node'. While at the same time the whole left panel of VS Code, including the File Viewer, is still based on the 'admin' node.

Any suggestions and advice are welcome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If your job script runs successfully, then it should run on a compute node. You can always check your job status using `squeue -u $USER`. It will tell you the node name so you can recognize which job is running on which node.

Comment: As far as switching between login and compute node. You can run multiple ssh connections within VS code or even in the terminal.

Comment: Hi @PrakharSharma, thanks for your comment! I was not submitting a whole script but doing interactive jobs. To do so, I hit "R: Create R terminal" and open the new terminal, where there's no information about if the terminal is run on compute node or not.

Comment: Interactive jobs too have a single line of code. People use `srun` followed by `salloc`. If you managed to run a R terminal as a job. Just open another ssh connection in new terminal and type `squeue -u $USER` to see where your job is running.

Answer (score 0):

In the R syntax, use `Sys.info()` to find the hostname of the computer R is running on:

```
> Sys.info()["nodename"]
          nodename
"node002.cluster"
```